# yii2 How to change user password via actionUpdate?

Tags: passwords, action, yii2

I have advanced app. I create CRUD for User model. So i got update action. I tried to update password by adding

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
```

But it call error, something like "password is write-only variable"

I tried to use field

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'new_password')->passwordInput() ?>
```

With adding in actionUpdate `model->setPassword($this->new_password);` and it throw `Getting unknown property: common\modules\user\controllers\DefaultController::new_password`.
But `model->setPassword('123456');` successfully setting pussword `123456`.

How can i get `new_password` field from view, to put it in `model->setPassword('there');`

Or maybe exist best way to do it?

**UPD**

I tried do it. Is not work.

```
  public function beforeSave($insert)
  {
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
      if ($this->new_password) {
        $this->setPassword($this->new_password);
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**UPD2**

```
  public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
  }
```

And password_hash writing in database. I can easy change hash, via generated CRUD, but don't know how to use `setPassword()` in updateAction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try write `updatePassword` function like `setPassword` with another variable

```
 public function updatePassword($new_password) {
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($new_password);
  }
```

declare a variable

```
public $new_password;
```

And add it in rules()

```
  public function rules() {
    return [
      //...
      ['new_password', 'required'],
      ['new_password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
    ];
  }
```

And at `actionUpdate` in your controller add

```
$model->updatePassword($model->new_password);
```

This should help

Answer (score 1):

Here "$this" is your Controller which of course, doesn't have 'new_password' property. You'd better not set new password in controller, but do it in model, for example in beforeSave method:

```
if ($this->new_password) {
    $this->setPassword($this->new_password);
}
```

Comment: Look on update question. I tried and not get success. May be i did it wrong?

Comment: Try to debug it and see whether script gets into that "if" statement or not. There may be different reasons: for example, your 'new_password' must be in rules() method - e.g. ['new_password', 'string']. Again we don't know what 'setPassword' method does. Does it return anything, or, I guess, it does something like "$this->password = $password".

Comment: I add rules, but it is don't work. Id add `setPassword` metod in question. I dont know how to debug it.

Comment: You may place there something like "die($this->new_password);" and see current value. You could learn how to debug in your IDE too.